# How do you update the results of a dropdown menu in tkinter to pass it to a function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to pass the results of a dropdown menu to a function so it can use those as inputs for a crafting minigame. However, the variables just get set to the default for the dropdown menus, which isn't helpful at all. I don't really know how .update() works, beyond reading that a lot of people think it should be avoided at all costs. I would just grab them after the button is pressed, but when I have it so the results show up on the same page as the dropdown it has the same problem I'm having with the button to begin with: it runs at when the page comes up and then doesn't update when I press the button.

The following is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
from functools import partial

menu = Tk()
menu.title('Level 3 Crafting')
menu.geometry("1080x1600")

ingredient1  = ["Time", "Love", "Truth", "Cruelty", "Mortality", "Earth", "Air", "Water", "Fire", "Magic",]
ingredientAlch = ["Aqua Vitae", "Antimony", "Cinnebar", "Vitriol", "Mercury", "Gold", "Oxygen", "Vinnegar", "Sulfur", "Platinum",]
#other crafting ingredient 2's
ingredient3 = ["Embroidery", "Needle", "Fabric", "Beiline", "Dye", "Metal Sheet", "Sack", "Wool", "Fiber Ash", "String", "Carved Obelisk", "Attraction Circle", "Binding Rune",
               "Blood Mark", "Death Knell", "Dirt", "Extinguishing Breath", "Etched Droplet", "Line of Flame", "Strand of Aether", "Crystal", "Opal", "Lapis Lazuli", "Diamond", "Glass Bead", "Chain",
               "Twine", "Pearl", "Amber", "Waxed String", "Aqua Vitae", "Antimony", "Cinnebar", "Vitriol", "Mercury", "Gold", "Oxygen", "Vinnegar", "Sulfur", "Platinum", "Bread", "Stew",
               "Clarified honey", "Incredibly Spicy Pepper", "Fried Dough", "Meat", "Mousse", "Rice", "Potato", "Dumpling", "Rabbit's Foot", "Strip of Darkness", "Lightning in a Bottle",
               "Pheonix Feather", "Spectral Antler",]


def CSVReader(csvFileName):
    rawdata=[]
    file=open(csvFileName,"r")
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        #print(row)
        rawdata.append(row)
    file.close()
    return rawdata

def Craft(mode):
    wCraft = Toplevel()
    menu.title('Crafted')
    menu.geometry("400x400")
    
    fileName = mode + ".csv"
    recipe = CSVReader(fileName)
    thing = []
    piece = 0

    track1 = []
    track2 = []
    track3 = []
    recipe = []

    print(i1)
    print(i2)
    print(i3)
    
    #check which items have ingredients
    for i in range(len(recipe)):
        if recipe[i][0]==i1:
            track1.append(i1 + " is an ingredient in " + recipe[i][3])
            piece = piece+1
        if recipe[i][1]==i2:
            track2.append(i2 + " is an ingredient in " + recipe[i][3])
            piece = piece+1
        if recipe[i][2]==i3:
            track3.append(i3 + " is an ingredient in " + recipe[i][3])
            piece = piece+1
        print(piece)
        #if piece == 3:
            #thing.append(recipe[i][3])
        piece = 0
        
    if len(thing)==0:
        thing.append("You Made Nothing")
        thing.append("Try again with this information:")
        
    write1 = Label(wCraft, text = thing[0])
    write2  = Label(wCraft, text = thing[1])
    write1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    write2.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    for d in range(len(track1)):
        write3 = Label(wCraft, text = track1[d])
        write3.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    for e in range(len(track2)):
        write4 = Label(wCraft, text = track2[e])
        write4.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
    for f in range(len(track3)):
        write5 = Label(wCraft, text = track3[f])
        write5.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

    #track1 = []
    #track2 = []
    #track3 = []

def alchCraft():
    alch = Toplevel()
    alch.title("Level 3 Alchemy")
    alch.geometry("1080x1600")

    Bit1 = StringVar()
    Bit1.set("Ingredient 1")
    alchI1 = OptionMenu(alch, Bit1, *ingredient1)
    #alchI1.config(width = 10)
    Bit2 = StringVar()
    Bit2.set("Ingredient 2")
    alchI2 = OptionMenu(alch, Bit2, *ingredientAlch)
    #alchI2.config(width = 10)
    Bit3 = StringVar()
    Bit3.set("Ingredient 3")
    alchI3 = OptionMenu(alch, Bit3, *ingredient3)
    #alchI3.config(width = 10)

    alchI1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    alchI2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    alchI3.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

    alchI3.trace("w", command = partial(Craft, "Alchemy"))
    
    i1 = alchI1.cget("text")
    i2 = alchI2.cget("text")
    i3 = alchI3.cget("text")
    
    butCraft = Button(alch, text = "Craft", command = partial(Craft, i1, i2, i3, "Alchemy"))
    butCraft.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    
    alch.mainloop()
    
#more functions for the other buttons. They'll all look very similar to what's in alchCraft once I get alchCraft working. Ideally they'll all call the same Craft function

butAlch = Button(menu, text="Alchemy", command = alchCraft)
#more buttons for other crafting sections

butAlch.grid(row=0, column=0)
#more buttons for other crafting sections


menu.mainloop()
```

If I have Craft exist on the same page as the option boxes, I'll pass the window to Craft as well

Answer (score 0):

**First:** your `Craft(mode)` function does as of now not accept any ingrediens, only the mode. Your variables `i1`, `i2` and `i3` created in `alchCraft` are not the same in `Craft` as those functions have different [scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)!

**Second:** what do you have `StringVar()` (`Bit1` ect) for if you try to get the value of the `OptionMenu` object (`alchI1` etc) by `.cget("text")`? Use the `.get()` method of the `StringVar` instead.

**Third:** you can pass the `StringVar` of the dropdowns with a lambda expression to `Craft` and call `get()` inside. If you assign e.g. `i1 = Bit1.get()` in `__init__` you will assign the placeholder value. You should `get()` the value whenever you need it, not just once at the begining!

Since your code is way to broad and not running on its own I have reduced your `alchCraft` to a little tkinter app (you can run this code and see how it behaves).

You can either pass the `StringVar` to `Craft` or the respective `get()` function using a lambda function (my `Craft` prints the selected items to the console).

Or if you use a OOP approach and set `i1` etc as instance variables you can access them without passing them down (this is what i have done in the second approach).

With this you should be able to implement the logic into your app:

```py
from tkinter import *

ingredient1 = ["Time", "Love", "Truth", "Cruelty", "Mortality", "Earth", "Air", "Water", "Fire", "Magic", ]
ingredientAlch = ["Aqua Vitae", "Antimony", "Cinnebar", "Vitriol", "Mercury", "Gold", "Oxygen", "Vinnegar", "Sulfur",
                  "Platinum", ]
# other crafting ingredient 2's
ingredient3 = ["Embroidery", "Needle", "Fabric", "Beiline", "Dye", "Metal Sheet", "Sack", "Wool", "Fiber Ash", "String",
               "Carved Obelisk", "Attraction Circle", "Binding Rune",
               "Blood Mark", "Death Knell", "Dirt", "Extinguishing Breath", "Etched Droplet", "Line of Flame",
               "Strand of Aether", "Crystal", "Opal", "Lapis Lazuli", "Diamond", "Glass Bead", "Chain",
               "Twine", "Pearl", "Amber", "Waxed String", "Aqua Vitae", "Antimony", "Cinnebar", "Vitriol", "Mercury",
               "Gold", "Oxygen", "Vinnegar", "Sulfur", "Platinum", "Bread", "Stew",
               "Clarified honey", "Incredibly Spicy Pepper", "Fried Dough", "Meat", "Mousse", "Rice", "Potato",
               "Dumpling", "Rabbit's Foot", "Strip of Darkness", "Lightning in a Bottle",
               "Pheonix Feather", "Spectral Antler", ]


class AlchCraft(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Level 3 Alchemy")
        self.Bit1 = StringVar(value="Ingredient 1")
        self.alchI1 = OptionMenu(self, self.Bit1, *ingredient1)
        self.Bit2 = StringVar(value="Ingredient 2")
        self.alchI2 = OptionMenu(self, self.Bit2, *ingredientAlch)
        self.Bit3 = StringVar(value="Ingredient 3")
        self.alchI3 = OptionMenu(self, self.Bit3, *ingredient3)

        self.alchI1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.alchI2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.alchI3.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.butCraft = Button(self, text="Craft",
                               command=lambda a=self.Bit1, b=self.Bit2, c=self.Bit3:
                               print(f'Crafting {a.get()} + {b.get()} + {c.get()}!'))
        self.butCraft.grid(row=1, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    alch = AlchCraft()
    alch.mainloop()
```

**EDIT** second approach with shared scope:

```py
class AlchCraft(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Level 3 Alchemy")
        Bit1 = StringVar(value="Ingredient 1")
        alchI1 = OptionMenu(self, Bit1, *ingredient1)
        Bit2 = StringVar(value="Ingredient 2")
        alchI2 = OptionMenu(self, Bit2, *ingredientAlch)
        Bit3 = StringVar(value="Ingredient 3")
        alchI3 = OptionMenu(self, Bit3, *ingredient3)

        alchI1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        alchI2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        alchI3.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.i1 = Bit1.get
        self.i2 = Bit2.get
        self.i3 = Bit3.get

        self.butCraft = Button(self, text="Craft", command=lambda: self.Craft('Alchemy'))
        self.butCraft.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def Craft(self, mode):
        print(f'Doing {mode} with {self.i1()}, {self.i2()} and {self.i3()}!')
```

Comment: 1. I was in the middle of troubleshooting the code and forgot to put i1, i2, and i3 back into Craft before submitting the code. Thank you. What do you mean, they have different scopes?
2. I tried to use the .get but got an error saying .get didn't exist for optionmenu. The closest I could find to replace it was .cget, but I don't really understand the difference.
3.I didn't realize I could use .get in the button command itself, thank you!

Comment: When you have two functions both with a variable inside called `var` then those are two different variables with the same name but in different scopes. So if you set `var` in the first function with a value this value is not set for `var` in the second one. You can assign `var` outside of the functions and call it with `global` in both functions to acces the same object. [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

Comment: Now take a close look at what object you try to `get()` and what the error says. You do not want to `get()` the OptionMenu object but the assigned StringVar which holds the current value. So instead of calling `alchI1.cget("text")` you have to call `Bit1.get()`. In your function you could edit the button command like: `command=lambda i1=Bit1, i2=Bit2, i3=Bit3: Craft(i1.get(), i2.get(), i3.get(), "Alchemy")`

Comment: I edited my answer to explain a little more about scope and what to pass down to `Craft`

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful

Comment: Glad to help! Maby consider accepting my answer?